# How can I trigger the mousedown event in a form with over 600 controls, including labels?

Tags: ms-access, events, event-handling, mouseevent

I have a form in MS Access with a subform inside it. And in this subform, I have a bunch of controls - more than 600 controls. Some of them are labels but most are textboxes. Also, a few buttons.
My intention is to make a routine to be executed when one of these controls is clicked. In some cases this can be done with the click event but in other cases just the mousedown event can be considered because there are different actions for each control. So it is important to use just the mousedown event.
So I want the mousedown event to be triggered in the form, no matter what control is being pressed, otherwise I would have to write a routine for every control.
What I'm experiencing is that when the mouse is pressed inside a clear area of the detail section of the form, the event mousedown is triggered. But when I click over a label the event does not occur.
How can I trigger the event mousedown when the mouse is left pressed over a label from the form's perspective? Thank you for helping.

I have tried to let the mousedown event clear on the control but used the property mousedown in the form. But when I press the mouse over a clear space in the form, I have the event. But when I press the mouse over the label, I don't have the event triggered.

I have tried to fill the property double click in the control with a dummy procedure, but it also didn't work.

I expected the routine in form_mousedown to be executed when the label is left pressed. But it is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

Implement *WithEvents*, a basic example you can find in my article:

[Create Windows Phone Colour Palette and Selector using WithEvents](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/29554/Create-Windows-Phone-Colour-Palette-and-Selector-using-WithEvents.html?preview=yawJg2wkMzc%3D)

Full code - too much to list here - at my repository at **GitHub**:

[VBA.ModernTheme](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.ModernTheme).